# bootstrap-datepicker-rails on rails4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with `bootstrap-datepicker-rails`. I am writing project on rails 4 and I've installed the gem. My application.css looks like:

```
*= require_self
*= require bootstrap-datepicker
*= require_tree .
```

My application.js looks like:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require_tree
```

The datepicker is working but it does not include the styles. My html for it is:

```
%input{"data-behaviour" => "datepicker", type: "text"}/
:javascript
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-behaviour~=datepicker]').datepicker();
  })
```

It looks like this:

[image: screenshot of datepicker]

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I see that styles for this gem has other class than i have in my html when i add datepicker to class styles changes a little bit but it still looks awfull

Comment: Which version bootstrap are you running? I think the gem works only with bootstrap 2.3.2

Comment: I use this gem : https://github.com/lubieniebieski/bootstrap-datetimepicker-rails
and now everything is fine

Comment: cool, please add the answer and mark it as answered later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I use this gem](http://github.com/lubieniebieski/bootstrap-datetimepicker-rails)   and now everything is fine –