# How to split "f.date_select" into 3 select boxes manually?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, date, form-for

When I use the helper

> = f.date_select :date_of_birth

it will generate 3 select boxes next to each other:

```
<select id="user_date_of_birth_3i" name="user[date_of_birth(3i)]">...</select>
<select id="user_date_of_birth_3i" name="user[date_of_birth(2i)]">...</select>
<select id="user_date_of_birth_3i" name="user[date_of_birth(1i)]">...</select>
```

So one Rails helper will create these 3 select boxes.
I would need to put there a Rails helper, that would generate only one select box, like:

> = f.date_select :date_of_birth_3i

(but this generate an error)

would generate

```
<select id="user_date_of_birth_3i"> name="user[date_of_birth(3i)]">...</select>
```

and the same for the two other select boxes...

Is there any way to achieve that?

Thank you

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19515053/bootstrap-datepicker-rails-on-rails4 or this: https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails or this: https://github.com/zpaulovics/datetimepicker-rails

Comment: This is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I just came up with a solution based on the form tag helper [select_year](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-select_year) and friends:

```
<%=
  select_year(
    my_object.date_field.try(:year),
    {
      :prompt => "",
      :start_year => Time.zone.now.year,
      :end_year => Time.zone.now.year + 4,
      :field_name => :"date_field(1i)",
      :prefix => :my_object
    },
    :class => "form-control"
  )
%>
```

This is kind of ugly because it not taking any information from the surrounding `form` and we have to set up the selected value, the *special* field_name with the *(1i)* and such.

So I ended up with a helper:

```
module DateSelectHelper
  def date_select_year(object, field_name, opts = {}, html_opts = {})
    merged_opts = {
      :prompt => "",
      :start_year => Time.zone.now.year,
      :end_year => Time.zone.now.year + 4,
      :field_name => :"#{field_name}(1i)",
      :prefix => object.class.name.underscore
    }.merge(opts)

    select_year(object.send(field_name).try(:year), merged_opts, html_opts)
  end

  def date_select_month(object, field_name, opts = {}, html_opts = {})
    merged_opts = {
      :prompt => "",
      :field_name => :"#{field_name}(2i)",
      :prefix => object.class.name.underscore
    }.merge(opts)

    select_month(object.send(field_name).try(:month), merged_opts, html_opts)
  end

  def date_select_day(object, field_name, opts = {}, html_opts = {})
    merged_opts = {
      :prompt => "",
      :field_name => :"#{field_name}(3i)",
      :prefix => object.class.name.underscore
    }.merge(opts)

    select_day(object.send(field_name).try(:day), merged_opts, html_opts)
  end
end
```

And you can use it like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <%= date_select_year(f.object, :date_field, { :start_year => Time.zone.now.year, :end_year => Time.zone.now.year + 4 }, { :class => "form-control" }) %>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3">
  <%= date_select_month(f.object, :date_field, {}, { :class => "form-control" }) %>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-2">
  <%= date_select_day(f.object, :date_field, {}, { :class => "form-control" }) %>
</div>
```

I'm still testing it .. but it looks like it works.